Flutter cached_network_image 404 retry
Here I'm using cached_network_image to loading network image.
It may not exists with the giving image url, when I get 404 from errorListener, I async image to the url to make sure url is available. After that I refresh the CachedNetworkImage, still get error 404 from errorWidget.
Widget imgWidget() {
  return CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: _imageUrl,
    imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) {
      return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: imageProvider,
            fit: widget.fit,
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
    placeholder: (context, url) {
      return widget.placeholder;
    },
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) {
      return widget.placeholder;
    },
    errorListener: (e) {
      if (e is HttpException) {
        logger.d('----- errorListener ${e.uri.toString()} - ${e.message}');
        if (e.message.contains('404')) {
          _syncImage();
        }
      } else {
        logger.d('Image Exception is: ${e.runtimeType}');
      }
    },
  );
}

_syncImage() async {
  HttpManager().syncImageToCdnUrl(widget.picKey).then((_) {
    setState(() { });
  }).catchError((onError) {
    logger.d(onError);
  });
}
  

